# Finding the isometric view of an object from the front and right side view

Tags: technical-drawing, drafting, drawings

I need to draw the isometric view and top section view of the object given only the front and right side view.
[image]

[image]

I understand on how other edges of these views correlate with each other. I just do not get on what to do with this surface (highlighted with red).

[image]

Comment: The top left rectangle could also be a ramp (in both views).

Comment: The far right rectangle in both views could also be a ramp.

Comment: By the way, when you post questions like this then it wold be nice to know if you use first or third urn projection rule otherwise the answer gets confusing.

Comment: @jooja Although I totally agree, I think in this case its obvious that its third angle projection(?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My interpretation is the following (the dimensions are not exactly accurate).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: straight lines added]

I see 4-solutions. I added straight lines (in GIMP) to represent canted faces. Either the original posted by NMech along with either or both surfaces as canted are also viable alternatives.

(As NMech noted, they could have curvature (except you might then have to show the center of the arc, unless they were b-splines(?).)

Comment: +1 To further JimClark's point, additionally, one could use any the curve, instead of straight lines, at the places you made the changes. Or they could have the inverse slope from the one JimClark is showing.  I was lazy and opted for the straight line.

Answer (score 1):

My shot on the "top view".

[image]